# Is it possible to configure a virtualhost in a docker container with Apache?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-for-windows

I describe my doubt below:

I currently have Docker installed on my Windows computer. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 container, which has installed PHP 7.2, Apache2, and MariaDB. The port mapping is as follows:

`docker run -it --name my_container -p 8080:80 -p 8081:3306 ubuntu:1804`

Previously, before using Docker, I had configured a Virtual Host on my computer for a web project, something like `http://my_project.dev` to access it instead the typical `http://localhost/projects/my_project`.

Now that I changed my way of working to Docker, I have my project working perfectly on port 8080, something like this `http://localhost:8080/projects/my_project`, but I can't find a way to create a Virtual Host to access my project with `http://mi_project.dev` in my current Docker container.